any differences between "while(true) { code }" and "for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { code }"
supposed I have this code
while (true) {
  // do things
  if (condition) break;
}

if I can always determine that the while loop stops after less than n times during runtime, should I write this instead
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // do things
  if (condition) break;
}

this is clearly micro optimization and i should not worry about it too much. nevertheless I want to know the answer out of curiosity that if the compiler can use the extra information for some obscure optimizations.

You mean besides that one loop doesn't have a limit, and the other does? The for loop will always end, guaranteed (unless you modify i or n inside the loop), but the while loop may never end.

why do you think this would be optimization?

there are some compiler-specific extensions (namely openmp) that let you unroll the loops up to N iterations if N is a compile time constant, which is probably "easier" for a compiler to see through than a while loop with a complex body.
In the end, only the generated assembly can tell you where the difference between the two is

Generally, write code to express intent and leave optimizations for the compiler. You need to do something only when you measure and something is too slow. More specifically, depends on what //do things and what condition is.

"should I" is a matter of opinion, and thus off-topic here. Do you have a specific, objective concern or question?

In your scenario - when you know the loop will break early - then there's no functional difference.
For performance, however, you probably should use the while(true). The reason being that the branch at the end of the while(true) loop will be an unconditional branch back to the beginning. This means that any processor branch-predictor will not need to guess whether the branch is taken or not. In the for case the branch at the end is a predicated branch that is always taken. This means the branch predictor cannot be of any use and may get it wrong.
Also, the code doesn't need to maintain and update a count with the while loop which is a tiny win.
That said, this is the smallest of microoptimsations and unless this is on a really hot path what ever reads best and/or leads to less maintenance is the right solution. Even if you do choose to go down this route you'd probably want to run performance analysis on it to be sure.

The while loop could possibly run forever.  The for loop is limited.  IMHO, for most loops, you want a maximum iteration so your program doesn't run forever when it shouldn't.

you should use "while true" because of saving memory.

What? What memory do you save here?
